# svn update status

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

One of my file in working copy has status red and it is not updated however check with repository and there is new version available.

Trying to update with no luck working copy is still red and update.

My question is how to update?

Comment: Are you sure the content of the file has not been updated? Tortoise sometimes shows a red symbol on my machine even though the file has been updated.. Ohterwise: sure you have not got a conflict?

Comment: Do you have local changes in this file?

Comment: Check with TortoiseSVN via "check for modifications" this is the only realiable check if a file must be updated or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maby it got conflicted during Merge. Can you Edit Conflicts by right click on the file? If you are sure that you dont have any local updates just delete the file and update the repository again.

Comment: do you mean delete by tortoise? or by hand? I see that file is updated in repo but can't update it in working copy.

Comment: delete it by hand and then update the directory so you will get the last version of the file. but if you have any local changes (in that file) you will loose them.